# How to make an If function with 3 variables? Eclipse

Tags: java

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make a code that when a user enters 3 numbers the console outputs the biggest out of the 3. I know how to do it without if, but how do I do it with if function.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @Nikola Java Eclipse

Comment: which part are you having problems with? you know, you can first take the biggest of first two numbers, and then take the result of that and compare that to remaining third number

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hint: If you know how to compute the max out of 2 numbers, the max out of 3 is simply `max(a, max(b, c))`

Comment: @Mureinik well I made the input part where user can input in console the numbers, but I'm having trouble at the logical part where from a, b, c I have to tell the console that it needs to pick the highest value one by using If function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check out standard algorithm for finding the maximum element.

I will try to explain it.

I will assume that you have your 3 numbers in variables a, b and c, of type int.

First you declare a variable to store your maximum value. Let's call it max.
You should initialise max to one of the 3 numbers. Our initial assumption is that it is the smallest number.

```
int max = a;
```

Next, check if the second number is greater than the current maximum (variable max). If it is, we want to update max variable to hold the value of the second number. You can make that check using an **if statement**:

```
if(b > max)
    max = b;
```

At this point max has the value of the greater of the first two numbers.
For the last number, you can do the same check as in the previous step.

```
if(c > max)
    max = c;
```

Now max contains the largest of the three values.

In fact, if you had more than 3 numbers, you can just keep checking for the largest one in the same manner.

A complete program to find the largest of three numbers would look as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Biggest_Number 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int a, b, c;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the first number:");
        a = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the second number:");
        b = s.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the third number:");
        b = s.nextInt();

        int max = a;

        if(b > max)
            max = b;

        if(c > max)
            max = c;

        System.out.println("Largest number is: " + max);
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though this is way out of my comprehension zone.

Answer (score 0):

let a,b,c are three variable which use to store three nos.

```
int max=Math.max(Math.max(a,b),c);
System.out.println(max);
```

Hope, it clears your issue. But please google it, before posting such kind of questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
int a;
int b;
int c;

if(a>b && a>c){
    System.out.println(a);
}
if(b>a && b>c){
    System.out.println(b);
}
if(c>b && c>a){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

Comment: @Taspo Could you choose me as the correct answer?